# Is admin section completely customizable in terms of styling?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, functions, wp-admin

Can we completely customize the WordPress dashboard in terms of appearance and style? I have uploaded the image:[image]

Or Wordpress doesn't allow such conversions.

I mean the right-hand side part shown in the image.

Reason: I want to convert the part of this [HTML template](http://demo.interface.club/limitless/demo/bs4/Template/layout_2/LTR/default/full/index.html) into the admin dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the admin CSS and style it as per your requirements However it is not recommended as for the same you need to customize the core word press files which will be overridden on new WordPress update. However if require you can create the custom WordPress dashboard from your front end theme.

Comment: How → "However if require you can create the custom WordPress dashboard from your front end theme."

Comment: Customize you frontend theme in wp-content folder and convert the above HTML into wordpress.